# Use single local Stylesheet among different components in nextJs

Tags: reactjs, typescript, sass, next.js

How to use a single stylesheet among all the child/related components of a page?

For example, I have a page -->ProductList.tsx
it has a component         -->SortButton.tsx
I have to do
import style from "../../../styles/ProductList.module.scss";
on both the files (ProductList.tsx & SortButton.tsx)
is there any way that I have to import style only in ProductList.tsx and use it across all it child/related components ?

Answer (score 0):

Import the stylesheet in `pages/_app.js` and remove the imports from the page and component.